# React setState updater redundant parameters?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({ counter: prevState.counter + props.step }));

this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + this.props.step });
```

What's the practical difference between the above 2 calls?

Under what proper usage of React would `prevState` and `props` not be the same as `this.state` and `this.props`? Please provide an example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) etc if possible.

Comment: [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) & [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ktpk8k)

Comment: @azium shouldn't we batch all state changes into a single `setState` call instead of calling `setState` multiple times synchronously and relying on "React **may** batch multiple setState() calls"?

Comment: it's just an example. basically if you want to affect the next state based on current state, use a function since the state may not be what you expect at certain time, which you can see in the, albeit contrived example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to React documentation: **"`this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state."**
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

A detailed intuition can be found here **Guaranteeing Internal Consistency**:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710

In general, using `this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + this.props.step });`  is wrong, and you should **never** use it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    counter: 1
  };

  onClickHandler = () => {
    console.log("[onClickHandler]", this.state.counter);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClickHandler}>
        <ChildComponent
          val={this.state.counter}
          onIncrement={() => {
            console.log("[onIncrement]");
            this.onClickHandler();
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.val);
    return (
      <h2
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("[ChildComponent]", this.props.val);
          this.props.onIncrement();
        }}
      >
        {this.props.val}
      </h2>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Consider this example, the expected result should be counter update by 2 every click, but it's only update once!
Using `prevState` in `onClickHandler` will give you expected result.
Tested on CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/qkxrx06o46